# Getting 500 status after Serializing SqlDataReader into Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

Am getting statuss 500 error.Am not getting exactly where am doing wrong.
When i click on getcustomer button 'Getcustomers' method is called which retuns json .

**Script:**

```
<script>
    var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
    MyApp.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.helloAngular = "hello";
        $scope.GetCustomers = function () {
            debugger;
            $http.get("/Home/Getcustomers")
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.customerDetails = data;
                }).
                error(function (data, status, thrownError) {
                    //alert(status);
                    //alert(data.responseText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                });
        }
    });

</script>
```

Server side code:
I get json data from this function:

```
 public ActionResult Getcustomers()
        {
            string query = "select top 10 * from Customers ";
            ArrayList custArray = new ArrayList();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
            sqlcon.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                custArray.Add(new
                    {
                        Name = reader["ContactName"],
                        City = reader["City"],
                        PostalCode = reader["PostalCode"],
                        Country = reader["Country"],
                        Phone = reader["Phone"],
                    });

            }
           var result= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(custArray);
            sqlcon.Close();
            return Json(result);

        }
```

I have search ,but cant get where am going wrong.Plz help me.

Comment: 500 is an error wich come from your server. What's the logs on the server's side ?

Comment: @Apédémak when i debug it gives me the json data but not getting why its through 500 status

Comment: Well 500 is the "Internal server error". This is all about the server. When you said your JSON is fine, in wich part of your code is that ? In your var result ?

Comment: @Apédémak  yes in var result

Comment: Don't just downvote.If something is wrong or silly plz let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, At last got what i was missing.
As status 500 is server error.It was occuring because the reader was not closed
after reading the sqldatareader(I really make silly mistakes)

```
public ActionResult Getcustomers()
        {
            string query = "select top 10 * from Customers ";
            ArrayList custArray = new ArrayList();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
            sqlcon.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                custArray.Add(new
                    {
                        Name = reader["ContactName"],
                        City = reader["City"],
                        PostalCode = reader["PostalCode"],
                        Country = reader["Country"],
                        Phone = reader["Phone"],
                    });

            }
            //Clean sqldatareader here;
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
           var result= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(custArray);
            sqlcon.Close();
            return Json(result);

        }
```